# Custom AJAX Server

Tags: php, javascript, c, ajax, webserver

I have been looking at writing my own server using kqueue.   I can do this with really no problems as long as I can control what kind of client will be accessing our system.   Realistically, however, I would need to accept from standard web clients, including AJAX.   I have been looking for examples of programs that use XMLHTTPRequest to connect to a custom server written in C.  I have found nothing.

Can you help me?

Bruce

Answer (score 4):

Ajax just means "Making an HTTP request using JavaScript". It isn't a client.

As far as the server is concerned, there is no difference between an Ajax request and any other HTTP request.

(Some libraries add an experimental HTTP header to state that the request was trigged by Ajax, but when you care about that on the server, it is almost always at the application level rather than the server level (i.e. your server side script not your HTTPD)).